# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `text` on serializer `CommentSerializer`

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to make a Blog API. But I have been getting this error when I search for individual comments under each post.

The model, serializers and views for Comments is given below:

Models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model) :
    text = models.TextField(
        validators=[MinLengthValidator(3, "Comment must be greater than 3 characters")]
    )

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # Shows up in the admin list
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.post.title)
```

Serializers.py

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    post = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['text', 'created_at', 'post', 'owner']
```

Views.py

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    def get_object(self, queryset = None, **kwargs):
        item = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return get_list_or_404(Comment, post = item)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Comment.objects.all()
```

Whenever I go to http://localhost:8000/api/comments/1/ this is what happens.

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `text` on serializer `CommentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance.
Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'.
```

Comment: Why are you writing your own `get_object`?  Is something wrong with the provided one?  Also, you are returning a list (As the answer noted), not a single object.  Your error message indicates that as well.

Comment: @AndrewBacker I want all the comments from the backend under a single blog post. I dont want all the comments in the webpage, that's why.

Comment: I think you fundamentally do not understand the thing you are working with.

Comment: Viewsets are "list", "retrieve(single)", "create/update/delete(single)".  If you want some data for a single "blog", then do `/api/comments?post=xxx` or `/api/posts/:xx/comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be get_object_or_404(Comment, post = item) because get_list_or_404 is returning a list and get_object() should return a single object.

Comment: But I am expecting many comments from a single blog post. Not just a comment.

Comment: http://localhost:8000/api/comments/1/  this route will retrieve you the comment with id 1 if you correct the mistake from get_object method. If you want to get the comments from a blog post you should add the following to the viewset:
`class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        filterset_fields = ("post",)...`
And using Postman you will be able to get all the comments from a post using a get request: http://localhost:8000/comments?post=PostId